# concat collection in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to concatenate a set collection to another set of collection. I see in Laravel 5.5 it has `concat` function, but for compatibility reason I have to use until Laravel 5.3 only.

I tried `merge` function but it is not concatenating but merging instead.

What are other workaround, or how can I update the Laravel Collection without update the whole Laravel package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add functionality to `Illuminate\Support\Collection` via "macro"s if you want to:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Collection::macro('concat', function ($source) {
    $result = new static($this);

    foreach ($source as $item) {
        $result->push($item);
    }

    return $result;
});

$new = $someCollection->concat($otherOne);
```

Copied the method from 5.5.

I have a short blog post about macros in Laravel in general, if it helps:

[asklagbox blog - Laravel macros](https://asklagbox.com/blog/laravel-macros)

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Collections - Extending Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#extending-collections) Though this is from 5.5 docs `Collection` has had this macro functionality for awhile now.

Comment: @sulaiman updated macro example to be the method you need from 5.5

Answer (score 2):

Okay nevermind, I'm using code below as workaround,

```
$first_collection->each(function($element) use (&$second_collection) {

 $second_collection->push($element);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A `merge` function is just what you need.

[The documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge) says

> If the given items's keys are numeric, the values will be appended to the end of the collection:

Which is just what you need.

If you are not sure about items keys, you can always use `->values()` function

so the final design would be:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
...
$payments = new Collection();
$payments = $payments
            ->merge($payments1->values())
            ->merge($payments2->values());
```